# Change Button in Real Time on Server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, server, real-time

So, I'm trying to learn Socket.IO and Node.JS and whatnot. But I am having a really hard time trying to understand it.

I am trying to change the color of a box in real time by clicking in one browser and watching it change in another browser or on another device.

The HTML:

```
<article></article>
```

The CSS:

```
<style>
article {
background:red;
width:500px;
height:500px;
cursor:pointer;
}

   .green {
    background:green;
    }
</style>
```

The script I'm using is just trying to connect to the server I think:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Forgot to include the function:

```
<script>
$("article").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green");
});
</script>
```

Comment: what triggers the 'event' for the socket?

Comment: `The script I'm using is` ... creating a server, not connecting to one

Comment: See this is what I need help with lmao . I'm not understanding what else to do after that. And the function is toggling the .green Class to the Article

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do this is with Node.js + [Ably](https://www.ably.io) to deliver the notification message.

So for example your code would then look like this:

```
 <script>
 /* Instance the realtime message bus
 var ably = Ably.Realtime.new(apiKey); /* get a free key from www.ably.io */
 var channel = ably.channels.get("article");

 $("article").click(function() {
   /* Triggers all buttons to go green, assumes each article has a data-id */
   channel.publish("click", $("article").data('id'));
 });

 channel.subscribe("click", function(msg) {
   $("button").toggleClass("green");
 });
 </script>
```

Nice and simple :)

**Disclaimer - I am the co-founder of [Ably - simple better realtime](https://www.ably.io)**

Comment: +1. This is interesting. I wonder if you have thoughts about my new related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59384778/470749